# How do viewProviders and @Host work together in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-dependency-injection

Given the following example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yc4pus?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

```
@Injectable()
export class LogService {
  sayHello() {
    console.log('Hello World !');
  }
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <div>Child Component !</div>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(@Host() @SkipSelf() logService: LogService) {
    logService.sayHello(); // it prints 'Hello World !'
  }
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  imports: [ChildComponent],
  standalone: true,
  viewProviders: [LogService],
  template: `
    <h1>Parent Component</h1>
    <app-child></app-child>
  `,
})
export class ParentComponent {}
```

I don't understand why logService is correctly injected into ChildComponent despite having `@Host()` and `@SkipSelf()` decorators.

[@Host documentation](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-in-action#make-a-dependency-optional-and-limit-search-with-host) :

> The @Host property decorator stops the upward search at the host component. The host component is typically the component requesting the dependency. However, when this component is projected into a parent component, that parent component becomes the host.

[viewProviders documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Component#viewProviders) :

> Defines the set of injectable objects that are visible to its view DOM children

There is no projected content in this example, so the host component is `ChildComponent`.

The search should be stopped at `ChildComponent` and also be skipped for this component , so how can the DI framework see the `LogService` declared in `ParentComponent` viewProviders ?

I presumed `viewProviders` to do the same as providing the service into `ChildComponent` providers, but `@SkipSelf()` should prevent from searching inside this component.

Replacing `viewProviders` by `providers` produces the expected error `No provider for LogService found`.

The documentation about `viewProviders` is very light, I don't understand how it really work behind the scene.

Comment: This exact scenario (and comparison with providers) is described in the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/hierarchical-dependency-injection#host-and-viewproviders).

Comment: @Shlang Still don't understand, in their example they says `If you now add @Host() (in addition to the @SkipSelf()) to the @Inject of the FlowerService, the result will be null` whereas in my example the result is not null. Note that the viewProviders is in the ParentComponent, so usng `@Host` in ChildComponent should not let me see the `LogService` from the ParentComponent viewProviders.

Comment: This sentence is from a section about `providers`, there are 2 sections describing the behavior of these decorators specifically for the case of `viewProviders` below.

Comment: In this case, I don't know why declaring the service in the `providers` field doesn't work. Their sentence `@Host() causes the injector to look until it encounters the edge of the <#VIEW>` seems to be wrong, in this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2qspse?file=src%2Fapp.component.ts) I'm able to use `@Host` and inject a service declared in the `providers` array. According to the documentation, it should have stopped to the `<#VIEW>`

Comment: Again this sentence is from '@Host and viewProviders' section, but in your example, you define it in 'providers'. When no `<ng-content>` are involved, providers == viewProviders except `@Host() @SkipSelf` case - since the only place is used for search is parent #View => providers give null, and viewProviders give not null.

Comment: I misunderstood the sentence `@Host() causes the injector to look until it encounters the edge of the <#VIEW>`, actually the <#VIEW> refers to the parent component <#VIEW> not the current component <#VIEW>. It's all clear now, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I finally understood how DI resolution works, so I will answer my own question so it could be useful for others.

`@SkipSelf` skips the current component `providers` / `viewProviders`.

`@Host` stops the search when reaching the **viewProviders** of the host component (host component providers won't be reachable). 
 The host component is the one declaring the current component in its template.

From the example :

- `@SkipSelf` skips `ChildComponent` providers and viewProviders.
- `@Host` stops the search at `ParentComponent` viewProviders. The host component is `ParentComponent` because it declares `<app-child></app-child>` in its template.

So `LogService` is eventually resolved from `ParentComponent` viewProviders.

**Extra Notes about viewProviders and providers differences**

1. `viewProviders` are resolved before `providers`

```
@Injectable()
export class LogService {
  constructor(public message: string) {}
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  providers: [{
    provide: LogService,
    useValue: new LogService('Root providers'),
  }],
  viewProviders: [{
    provide: LogService,
    useValue: new LogService('Root viewProviders'),
  }],
  template: `{{logService.message}}`, 
  // print 'Root viewProviders'
})
export class RootComponent {
  constructor(public logService: LogService) {}
}
```

2. `viewProviders` and `providers` dependency resolution differs when using content projection.

`viewProviders` are only visible to the components declared in the template view.

```
@Injectable()
export class LogProvidersService {
  constructor(public message: string) {}
}

@Injectable()
export class LogViewProvidersService {
  constructor(public message: string) {}
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ParentComponent, ChildComponent],
  providers: [{
    provide: LogProvidersService,
    useValue: new LogProvidersService('Root providers'),
  }],
  viewProviders: [{
    provide: LogViewProvidersService,
    useValue: new LogViewProvidersService('Root viewProviders'),
  }],
  template: `
    <app-parent>
      <app-child></app-child>
    </app-parent>
  `,
})
export class RootComponent {}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  standalone: true,
  providers: [{
    provide: LogProvidersService,
    useValue: new LogProvidersService('Parent providers'),
  }],
  viewProviders: [{
    provide: LogViewProvidersService,
    useValue: new LogViewProvidersService('Parent viewProviders'),
  }],
  template: `<ng-content></ng-content>`,
})
export class ParentComponent {}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
    <p>{{logProvidersService.message}}</p>
    <p>{{logViewProvidersService.message}}</p>
  `,
  // print 'Parent providers'
  // print 'Root viewProviders'
})
export class ChildComponent {
  constructor(
    public logProvidersService: LogProvidersService,
    public logViewProvidersService: LogViewProvidersService
  ) {}
}
```

I created a [stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eqvcqr?file=src%2Fmain.ts) in case you want to play with it.

To resolve `viewProviders`, you should ask yourself "In which template is declared `app-children` tag ?". The answer is `RootComponent` so it has access to its `viewResolvers` (along with those from its ancestor if any).

It doesn't have access to `ParentComponent` `viewResolvers` because content projection (through `ng-content`) is used, `viewResolvers` are not accessible to projected content.